# Creating a form in a different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a movies controller and a searches controller.  In my searches controller I have the ability to search for a movie from IMDB.  I am trying to make a form where I can click Add movie to library and trying to make a new entry in my movies table.

In my searches controller i have

```
    def new
        @search = Search.new
        @movie = Movie.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @search }
    end
  end
```

In my searches index view I have

```
<%= simple_form_for(@movie) do |f| %>
<%= f.input :title, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => "Skyfall" } %>
<%= f.input :year, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => "2012" } %>
<%= f.input :description, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => "James Bond" } %>
<%= f.association :genres, include_blank: false, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => "some value" } %>
<%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

I get a NoMethodError in Searches#index followed by undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is ok, I mean, you are putting a new object in @movie on the controller, which is totally fine.

Just make sure you add the new instance of the object in Search#index, like this:

```
def index
  @movie = Movie.new
end
```

You are getting the error because when the view form is evaluated on this line:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@movie) do |f| %>
```

@movie is nil, so model_name is not a method of the object nil and you get the exception.

Comment: Thank you.  I usually set up my index methods @movies = Movie.all.  I now understand why I just needed to create the instance since that is where the form is.